# C++ : cannot convert * to (*)[] in assignment

Tags: c++, templates

Im working on a template class which represents a managed Array.

```
E (*data)[];
```

data is my array.

```
data = new E[size];
```

And this, it doesn't like. it throws me;

> cannot convert Component* to Component (*)[] in assignment
>   What gives?

Also can anyone explain why E is denoted with a * even though I didn't pass a pointer type into my template type?

Comment: Per your edit, I addressed this problem already in my response.  Your first question was misleading; you need to call `new E*[size];`  You also need to make `data` an `E**` as you cannot assign to an array.

Comment: @EdS. My edit was after the fact Tony gave me some pointers ( no pun intended ). My original question still stands. Thats why I removed it again. But everything works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your `data` member an `E*`.  You will still be able to index array-style ala `data[i]` (that notation, when used with a pointer and integral value, basically means add the pointer and i times the size of the pointed-to objects).

EDIT:

```
template <typename E>
class X
{
    X(int initial_size) : data_(new E[initial_size]), size_(initial_size) { }
    X(const X& rhs) : data_(new E[rhs.size_]), size_(rhs.size_) { std::copy(...); }
    ~X() { delete[] data_; }
    void capacity(int new_size)
    {
        E* p = new E[new_size];
        std::copy(p, p + new_size, data_);
        delete[] data_;
        data_ = p;
        size_ = size;
    }
    ...
  private:
    E* data_;
    int size_;
};
```

Comment: Could you add more to your answer? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: throws me: incompatible types in assignment of ComponentA* to ComponentA* [0]

Comment: @Sidar: I can't imagine how you managed that ;-).  I've fleshed out a couple illustrative functions....

Comment: @Sidar: Realize that this serves only as an example.  If you use this class in your code be aware of [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: Yes I guess I hit that wall as well. But creating that array seems to be the biggest problem. =[

Comment: @Sidar: Have you read my response?  I can't imagine that it doesn't cover your problem here.  If not then show us your *exact code* which fails to compile.

Answer (score 3):

```
E (*data)[];
```

`data` is a pointer to an array of E, not a pointer to E (and not to be confused with an array of pointer to E).  There is a very appreciable difference.

EDIT:  To help you understand...

`new` is returning to you a pointer to `E`, yet you have declared `data` as *a pointer to **array** of E*.  An array is a type in C!  It is not simply a pointer in disguise. An array may *decay* into a pointer in certain situations, but it doesn't go both ways.

EDIT 2:

Per your comment:

> I was under the impression that I was creating a new array of E pointers?

Go to http://cdecl.org/

First, type in:

```
int (*data)[];
```

Read what it says.  Now type:

```
int *data[];
```

Read again and note that it is not saying the same thing.  One as a pointer to array of int, one is an array of pointers to int.  Big difference.

If you want to dynamically allocate an array of pointers then `data` should be declared as:

```
E **data;
```

And then

```
data = new E*[size];
```

Comment: @Sidar: Then why the confusion?  A pointer to an array of E is *completely and utterly* different than a pointer to E.  An array in C is its own type, it is not simply a masked pointer (though it can *decay* into a pointer in certain situations)

Comment: I was under the impression that I was creating a new array of E pointers?

Comment: @Sidar: No; you are creating a pointer to array of E, not an array of pointers to E.  There is a significant difference.  I'll add an example

Comment: @Sidar: I added another example, this should get you running.

Comment: I would have accepted your answer as well. But thats not how the system works. I still want to thank you. So thanks =D

Comment: @Sidar, If you're unsure of what your declaration means, you can always use the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). It's basically the mental form of cdecl.

Comment: @chris: `void ** (*d) (int *(*d)[10], char **(*)(char *, char **));` <-- spiraling out of control (though it does work!) :D